# How to read timepicker's time into string

Tags: android, string, timepicker

I have a timepicker class and can show the time after picked.
My question is how to I write a function to retrieve the time (from mTimeDisplay) in the string form instead of text view?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);


    //Pick time's click event listener
    mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }

    });




}

    // update time
    public void updatetime()
    {
        mTimeDisplay.setText(


                    new StringBuilder()
                            .append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
                            .append(pad(mminute))
                            .append(" to ")
                            .append(pad(mhour2)).append(":")
                            .append(pad(mminute2))
                            ); 
        }

        private static String pad(int c) {
            if (c >= 10)
                return String.valueOf(c);
            else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get like this way

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
.append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
.append(pad(mminute))
.append(" to ")
.append(pad(mhour2)).append(":")
.append(pad(mminute2));

String time = sb.toString() // or you can get directly value from sb.toString() as per you requirement
```

and put this line into comment

```
/* mTimeDisplay.setText(
new StringBuilder()
 .append(pad(mhour)).append(":")    
.append(pad(mminute))
 .append(" to ")
.append(pad(mhour2)).append(":")
.append(pad(mminute2))
); */
```

Answer (score 1):

The [TextView.getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) method returns `CharSequence` which you can either use directly or convert to string using the `toString` method, e.g.

```
String time = mTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
```